# How to calculate expected value? Soccer possession

Tags: probability

I'm putting together a model to simulate, during a soccer game, which team has possession of the ball.

In my model, the match time ticks at a rate of 1 game minute per real second. This is in Excel. Possession starts with the home team.
At kick-off, they have, say, P(h) to keep the ball (for that minute) and 1 - P(h) to lose it to the away team.
The same for the away team; for each minute that they have the ball, they have P(a) chance to keep it and 1 - P(a) to turn it over.

How could I calculate an expected value for the possession figures over 90 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This game can be modeled by 2-state Markov chain; let $X_n=1$ represents possession by the home team on $n$-th minute and $X_n=2$ represents possession by the away team. Defining transition probability as $p_{ij}=\Bbb P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i)$, we get the transition probability matrix $$P=(p_{ij})_{i,j=1}^2=\left[\begin{array}{cc}p(h)&1-p(h)\\1-p(a)&p(a)\end{array}\right].$$ If initial distribution is given by $\pi_0=(1,0)^T$, which represents $\Bbb P(X_0=1)=1$, $\Bbb P(X_0=2)=0$, then the distribution of $X_n$ is given by $\pi_n=P^n \pi_0$. Note that the number of possessions by the home team over 90 minutes is given by
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{89} 1_{\{X_i=1\}},
$$ hence the expected value is
$$
N=\sum_{i=0}^{89} \Bbb E[1_{\{X_i=1\}}]=\sum_{i=0}^{89} \Bbb P[X_i=1].
$$ Since $\Bbb P[X_i=1]$ is the first component of the vector $\pi_i$, it follows
$$
N=\sum_{i=0}^{89} \langle(1,0), \pi_i\rangle =  (1,0)\left[\sum_{i=0}^{89} P^i \right]\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right).
$$ Expected value for the away team can also be calculated by $90-N$.

Comment: In the limit of infinitely long games, I would expect the probability of each team to have the ball to reach a steady state, given by an eigenvector of the matrix. Say team 1 has the ball with probability $p$. Then $90p$ should be a decent approximation of $N$ (I would estimate a relative error of less than $10\%$).

Comment: In fact, since the "P", probability that a team with the ball keeps it, is the same for both teams, it should be evident that in a 90 min game, the expected value for the time each team has possession is  90/2= 45 minutes.

Comment: @user247327 why "$P$"  is the same for the home team and away team? Am I missing something? It is not assumed that $p(h)=p(a)$. And even if $p(h)=p(a)$ is true, the home team takes the advantage of keeping the first ball. So the situation is not symmetric.

Comment: I think I misread the original post: At kick-off, they have, say, P(h) to keep the ball (for that minute) and 1 - P(h) to lose it to the away team. The same for the away team; for each minute that they have the ball, they have P(a) chance to keep it and 1 - P(a) to turn it over.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this out. I have finished my possession calculator in VBA, writing a custom function to estimate possession based on Home and Away team strength. It's perfect. Thank you.